# How to wait transaction query execution Express JS?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, transactions

I Have a chain of queries created using transaction.

- insert a new User. From the result I get the idUser
- insert a new Address. From the result I get the idAdress.
- insert a new user_address (using idUser and idAddress).

So I need to wait for each execution to proceed because the result of the first query is undefined!

```
connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error")); //! or error.message
    }
    var idUser;
    var idAddress;

    //insert user
    sql =
      "INSERT INTO users (email, password) " +
      "VALUES ( ?, ?)";
    param = [email, password];

    connection.query(sql, param, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
        connection.rollback(function () {
          return next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error")); 
        });

        //MY TEST: results is undefined
        console.log(results);

        //get the id
        idUser = results.insertId; 

        //insert user
        sql =
          "INSERT INTO addresses (country, city) " +
          "VALUES ( ?, ?)";
        param = [country, city];

        connection.query(sql, param, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
            connection.rollback(function () {
              return next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error")); 
            });

            // get the id
            idAddress = results.insertId;

            //insert user_address
            sql =
              "INSERT INTO user_address (idUser, idAddress) " +
              "VALUES ( ?, ?)";
            param = [idUser, idAddress];

            connection.query(sql, param, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                connection.rollback(function () {
                  return next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error")); 
                });

                //commit
                connection.commit(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        connection.rollback(function () {
                          next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error")); 
                    });
                });
        
            });

        });
    
    });

});
```

Comment: This uses callback code. It's really time to switch to using Promises and `async`/`await` as it will make your life *considerably* easier. Even better, use [Arrow functions like `(...) => { ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in preference to `function(...) { ... }`

Comment: ye @tadman do you know how to implement it with Promises ?!

Comment: I'd recommend using something like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) for your database layer and it natively supports promises. Many of the other drivers do as well, so you'll have to check the documentation for the one you're using.